# Laravel8 no me muestra las rutas mediante xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, rutas, composer

Tengo un problema con laravel8 estoy dando los primeros pasos, sucede de que cuando creo un proyecto en laravel8 mediante el comando:
laravel new proyecto
, y modifico las rutas en web.php agregando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

e intento entrar usando xampp mediante: localhost/Proyecto/public/saludo

no muestra nada... solo muestra 404 not found.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora ... si creo otro proyecto mediante:
composer create-project otroblog
y hago lo mismo en las rutas, e intento ingresar por xampp... me muestra correctamente el mensaje que especifique en la ruta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe por que sucede esto?... o que deberia de modificar en el primer proyecto para que funcione todo... (ojo no quiero crear un hosting virtual por que asi,  si funciona... o ingresando por: php artisan serve
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todo funciona,, pero por que al crear con composer no es necesario hacer hosting virtual ... alguien me podria explicar el por que pasa esto...

Comment: Para comenzar deberia de ser `/saludo` y es `xampp` , e investiga las razones comunes del 404 en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64332325/404-not-found-in-laravel-8) favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/481969/edit) para que podamos entender mejor lo que pasa y podamos ayudarte.